# How to continue executing script after ajax finished without making script synchronous nor by embedding content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronous

So, I know of two methods to wait for an ajax request with jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
```

This method will make ajax synchronous. I do not want that.

The second method that I know of is the following:

```
$.post("foo.html", function (foo) {
// Put all the rest of the code in here
});
```

I do not want to do that either.

Is there a third option, which involves a handler which 'listens' for the ajax request to be completed, and then runs the rest of the code?

I thought there might be.

Comment: Why don't you want to use $.post? It's just shorthand for $.ajax, which is what I would suggest.

Comment: No I do, you most likely misunderstood my question. I want a listener which listens for the completion of the `$.post` function.

Comment: as Sara said, what's wrong with using $.post? It does exactly what you ask. You can just create a method, say runAfterAjax(), and stick it in the callback for $.post()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Deferred objects in jQuery like this:

```
$.post("foo.html").done(function() { 
  alert("$.post succeeded"); 
});
```

You can find more information about Deferred objects in the [jQuery documentation: Deferred objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery $.ajax documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "foo.html",
}).done(function( response ) {
  // triggers when the ajax request is complete
  // 'response' contains any returned values
});
```

There are also .success() and .error() callbacks, if you prefer.